# Does the C++11 standard require that two iterations through a constant unordered_container visit elements in the same order?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

```
for (auto&& i : unordered_container)
{ /* ... */ }

for (auto&& i : unordered_container)
{ /* .. */ }
```

Does the standard require that both of these loops visit elements in the same order (assuming the container is unmodified)?

---

My analysis of this question...

I read the standard and as best I can tell the answer is "no"...

Since iterators of containers are forward, there is language that requires `a==b` imply that `++a==++b` for forward iterators. That means two iterations will go through the same path IF they both start in the same place. This reduces the question to a different question of whether the standard requires `container.begin() == container.begin()`. I couldn't find any language that requires this.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I was going to update with an exact quote from the standard, for forward iterators.... "a == b implies ++a == ++b". But that whole section was removed. Which is fine, I guess.

Comment: Assuming `begin()` always gives you the same iterator, these two loops _must_ be the same, otherwise you could not guarantee that either loop on its own visited each element once and only once.

Comment: @LouisBrandy: If you think it's a valid answer, then just post it in the answer area. If people think it's wrong, they can comment or downvote it.

Comment: @LouisBrandy: Yes, as I wrote in the edit description, if you feel you have an answer, then write it _as an answer_. The question section is for the _question_.

Comment: I'm not sure I can find a requirement that `container.begin() == container.begin()` must be true...

Comment: @Lightness I think you're wrong. The part you removed is not an answer, simply an analysis. Part of his question is if his analysis is correct. Further analysis would be required to find a full answer. This site generally encourages users to do some research before asking a question, and that's exactly what OP did. Don't strike him down for it.

Comment: @SchighSchagh Mate the first line was "My attempt at answering this question..."

Comment: I don't think using the word "answer" necessarily implies that I'm actually answering my own question. The reason I put that section is is because I've done some of the homework already and I wanted to save people time looking up relevant languages and sections. 

My "answer" is analysis that, if true, reduces my question to a different question. At any rate, I'll make an answer.

Comment: @Lightness But his analysis leaves the question of does the standard require `container.begin() == container.begin()`? He couldn't find such a requirement, but that doesn't mean he didn't miss it.

Comment: Completely orthogonal to the actual (and interesting) question: why do you care for order in an unordered container? ;-)

Comment: In addition to what @rubenvb said, I am interested in a the actual use-case.

Comment: @rubenvb: I have a multipass algorithm over the keys that is much more efficient if I can assume each pass visits elements in the same order. This can be solved by simply calling `begin` once and copying the OneTrue(tm) iterator whenever I need to start over, but the natural way to write the algorithm is a series of for-each loops, so I was curious.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Containers are required to implement `operator==()`. That is we can do:

```
container c;
c == c;
```

That relation is required to work the same as:

```
std::distance(a.begin(), a.end()) == std::distance(b.begin(), b.end()) &&
std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
```

The important part here is the call to `std::equal()`. This call requires that two independent calls to `container.begin()` will produce the same sequence of values. If it didn't, then `c == c` would be false, and that doesn't make any sense because `==` is an equivalence relation.

Therefore, my answer is that we **can** claim that the standard requires that two passes of **any** container must result in the same ordering. Obviously this requirement breaks if you do anything that changes the container or invalidates iterators.

#### Citations:

- C++ 2011 Table 96 — Container requirements

Comment: Nice. I think you've got it. For reference Table 17 defines "equivalence relation" and explicitly requires that a == a is true, for all a.

Comment: Language lawyer nitpick: Container comparison requires that the `value_type` is `EqualityComparable`. For non-EqualityComparable types, a container could therefore produce different orderings and still be standard-conforming.

Comment: @Casey: `value_type` of an `unordered_set` has to be `EqualityComparable` Obviously for the ordered containers the order is well defined, and for vector/list/deque the order is determined by insertion.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, but the answer states "two passes of **any** container." This may be the case for all containers defined in the standard, but it's not a consequence of the Container requirements themselves. It's possible to implement a (most likely pathological) container that produces different orderings for non-EqualityComparable elements while conforming to the Container requirements.

Comment: The cited requirements do not apply to unordered associative containers. See [unord.req]/p2: "Unordered associative containers conform to the requirements for Containers (23.2), except that the expressions
`a == b` and `a != b` have different semantics than for the other container types." This language has been present since at least N3337.

Answer (score 18):

I think @Sharth's conclusion is correct, but (for anybody who cares about newer standards) is already obsolete (and may not have ever reflected reality--see below).

More recent drafts of the standard (e.g., n3797) have changed the requirements, apparently intentionally *removing* the ordering requirement. Specifically, it says (§23.2.5/12):

> Two unordered containers `a` and `b` compare equal if `a.size() == b.size()` and, for every equivalent-key group [`Ea1`,`Ea2`) obtained from `a.equal_range(Ea1)`, there exists an equivalent-key group [`Eb1`,`Eb2`) obtained from `b.equal_range(Ea1)`, such that `distance(Ea1, Ea2) == distance(Eb1, Eb2)` and `is_permutation(Ea1, Ea2, Eb1)` returns true.

I also have relatively low confidence that implementations actually meet the requirements of the 2011 standard either. In particular, the unordered containers are normally implemented as hash tables with linked lists for collision resolution. Since those linked lists are expected to be short, they're not necessarily sorted (particularly since items stored in unordered containers aren't required to define operations to be used for sorting, such as `operator<`). This being the case, it's fairly routine for the linked lists to hold the same items, but in an order that depends upon the order in which they were inserted.

In such a case, it would be fairly routine for two hash tables that contained the same items that had been inserted in different orders to iterate over those items in different orders.

In theory such an implementation doesn't conform with the C++11 standard--but I'd guess the change cited above was made largely because that requirement couldn't be met in practice (because, as noted above, the container had no way to enforce ordering).

So, as long as you're dealing with the same container, unchanged, depending on iteration in the same order may be safe. Two containers that have the same contents may not work out so well though (and even in what claims to be a C++11 implementation, you probably can't expect it to meet tighter requirements than the newer drafts contain).

Comment: There are ways to enforce the ordering even with hash tables (e.g., keeping the entries also in a doubly-linked list, so maintaining insertion order; the hash table acts as a very fast way to index into the list) but they come with quite a bit of memory overhead.

Comment: @DonalFellows: The difficulty isn't with defining a hash table that *could* maintain order. The main difficulty arises when trying to impose ordering on types that don't define ordering.

Answer (score 3):

My read of the standard is that this is not guaranteed. 23.2.5, paragraph 6, states:

> Thus, although the absolute order of elements in an unordered
>   container is not specified, its elements are grouped into
>   equivalent-key groups such that all elements of each group have
>   equivalent keys. Mutating operations on unordered containers shall
>   preserve the relative order of elements within each equivalent-key
>   group unless otherwise specified.

Let's take off the table the fairly clear guarantee that elements that hash to the same key will have their relative order preserved no matter what. That seems to be fairly clear. Additionally, lets exclude any modifications to the container. In the remaining scope:

Although this doesn't actually explicitly define that the iteration order, in absence of changes to the container, is unstable, I interpret the statement "the absolute order of elements in an unordered container is not specified" on its literal face value. If the iteration order is undefined, then it is undefined, and is not guaranteed to be the same every time.

I think it all comes down to whether, in the quoted excerpt "is not specified" should be interpreted as "it could be anything" or "it could be anything, at any given time".

I think an argument can be made either way. I would interpret "is not specified" in the most strict, literal interpretation of the latter, but I wouldn't object too hard if someone would argue in favor of the former.

Answer (score 2):

Unordered containers do return forward iterators (which are defined in § 24.2.5) and those do have this property: `a == b implies ++a == ++b`. This seems to imply so long that `unordered_container.begin() == unordered_container.begin()` is true, that the traversal order will be the same.

I was unable to find any language that requires `unordered_container.begin() == unordered_container.begin()` which led me to a tentative answer of "no", the traversal order isn't required to be the same.

Comment: Can't quite follow your logic. Suppose `unordered_container.begin()` would not return the same element on consecutive calls, how then are the two resulting forward iterations both going to visit all elements? I think that is impossible.

Comment: Walter: I'm not sure why you think that's impossible. I don't think it's hard to come up with a contrived example. Imagine an internal storage using a circularly linked list. Your iterator would know where it started, and that's how it would know when to transition to end() when incremented for the final time.

Comment: You're also using that `a == b` if and only if either they're both end iterators or `*a` and `*b` are the same element of the container. Otherwise equality of iterators along the way doesn't prove they're iterating the elements in the same order. So, given that, you can prove what you need backwards from the end. Suppose in one iteration `++a == container.end()`. Then whatever element that points to, suppose `b` is the iterator for that element in the second iteration. That is `a == b`, and so `++b == container.end()`, and so that element is also last in the second iteration. By induction QED.